# Ternary Operator for jQuery If Statement

Tags: jquery, ternary-operator

I am wonder what is the cleanest way to write the below as a ternary operator:

```
if (jQuery('#product-options-wrapper select').val() || jQuery('#product-options-wrapper input').val()) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you don't really need a ternary operator here.

You would use:

```
jQuery('#product-options-wrapper select').val() || jQuery('#product-options-wrapper input').val() ? true : false
```

Which is exactly the same as :

```
jQuery('#product-options-wrapper select').val() || jQuery('#product-options-wrapper input').val()
```

If you want to return this you can use:

```
return !!(jQuery('#product-options-wrapper select').val() || jQuery('#product-options-wrapper input').val());
```

> Note the `!!` I used in order cast the value to boolean (true/false)

Comment: So it is not *exactly* the same.... I would suggest putting that `!!` already in the middle block to make the sentence above it true.

Comment: The code will work if you will use `if` in the caller, but if you will use `(if a === true)` you are right, it will not work the same. This is why I added the cast.

Answer (score -1):

"if(jQuery('#product-options-wrapper select').val() || jQuery('#product-options-wrapper input').val()) ? return true : return false;"
Will do the same thing

Comment: That is invalid syntax.

Comment: return jQuery('#product-options-wrapper select').val() || jQuery('#product-options-wrapper input').val() ? true : false;